# SQL query for last user action

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get an SQL statement to work which will show a list of users in the database and their last action.

The current table format is;

tblUser:
id, username, password

tblAction:
id, uid, action, date

The SQL statment I have at present is;

```
SELECT *
 FROM tblUser
 FULL OUTER JOIN Location
 ON tblUser.id=tblAction.uid
 WHERE action IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

I have used `limit 1` but this hasn't worked.

I have also tried;

```
SELECT *     
FROM tblAction T1    
WHERE date = (
   SELECT max(date)
   FROM tblUser T2
   WHERE T2.uid=T1.id
```

Please could someone help me?
This is an SQL command to be executed in an admin panel in PHP and is not MySQL.

Comment: when I have used `top 1` it only seems to return the most recent action, and not most recent by user

Comment: I provided an answer that should give you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  U.*,
            A.[action],
            A.[date],
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY U.id ORDER BY A.[date] DESC)
    FROM tblUser U
    LEFT JOIN tblAction A
        ON U.id = A.uid
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: I see it works nicely with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c50f71/2

I'm just trying to get it to work on the website as I get the error "Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given "

Comment: @jjharvey well, that seems like another question

Answer (score 1):

try use `RANK()/DENSE_RANK()/ROW_NUMBER()`

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bc0c/27)

**RANK:**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  a.*,
           b.action,
            b.date,
            Rk = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.[date] DESC)
    FROM tblUser a
    LEFT JOIN tblAction b
        ON a.id = b.uid
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE Rk = 1;
```

Comment: When I have used this it only shows the most recent action, and not most recent action by user.

e.g.
TOM - Login Failure - 18/03/15

instead of 
TOM - Login Failure - 18/03/15
DAVE - Request Signup - 18/03/15

Comment: It is still showing only one user (the user with the most recent action)
I'm trying to get it to show all the users; and the list shows their most recent action :)